# Which Google pricing is correct, from tha API usage or the maps platform?

Tags: api, google-maps, google-places, pricing, google-api

I'm doing PHP cURL requests to:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input={$address}&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address,name,geometry/location&key=$key&language=en-gb`

Based on [Google Places API Usage and Billing](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing) it should be free from what I can see

[image]

However [Google Maps Platform Pricing Table](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/?_ga=2.176378533.183903894.1574157534-619254240.1565009804#places) it is saying $17 per 1000 requests

What should I be looking at exactly? How much will it actually cost?

Comment: Did you manage to find some info? Basic data is free in the way you did that request?